# How to trim text from file and put it another file using python?

Tags: python

I have a text file called file1 like

```
    
        HelloWorldTestClass
        MyTestClass2
        MyTestClass4
        MyHelloWorld        
        ApexClass
    
    
        *
        ApexTrigger
    
    
        Book__c
        CustomObject
    
    56.0
```

Now i want to output my file as in file2 which contains `test` in the word and have output like this

```
        HelloWorldTestClass
        MyTestClass2
        MyTestClass4
```

I have a code like this

```
import re
import os

file_contents1 = f'{os.getcwd()}/build/testlist.txt'
file2_path = f'{os.getcwd()}/build/optestlist.txt'
with open(file_contents1, 'r') as file1:
    
    file1_contents = file1.read()
   
# print(file1_contents)

# output = [file1_contents.strip() for line in file1_contents if "TestClass" in line]
# # Use a regudjlar expression pattern to match strings that contain "test"
test_strings = [x for x in file1_contents.split("\n") if re.search(r"test", x, re.IGNORECASE)]
# x = test_strings.strip("['t]")
# # Print the result
with open(file2_path, 'w') as file2:
    # write the contents of the first file to the second file
    for test in test_strings:
        file2.write(test)
```

But it is outputting
        `HelloWorldTestClass        MyTestClass2        MyTestClass4`

I didn't find the related question if already asked please attached to it thanks

Comment: This is very little info to go off of. What exactly do you want to copy, the names or the relevant code aswell? Do you only want to copy classes or classes with "Class" in the name?

Comment: explain your cutting logic , why only 3 records?

Comment: i have edited the question please see it sorry for the trouble

Comment: You want the output in `file2` to be with the same number of tabs as in `file1`?

Comment: No i want to extract the word which contains `test` and print out as same as above `file2`

Comment: ok, show your minimal coding attempt

Comment: Asking to be sure - what about if the line contains `hello world Test` - do you want to extract the whole line or just the word `Test` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `in` operator with strings to check whether it contains your phrase:

```py
with open('file1.txt', "r") as f_input:
    with open('file2.txt', "w") as f_output:
        for line in f_input:
            if "test" in line.lower():
                f_output.write(line)
```